# How to bind command to the textbox in windows phone

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone-8

I want to bind a command to the textbox. I have tried  the below code. but it is not working.

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtReview" MaxLength="1000" Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay,Path=Comments}"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="215" Margin="10,184,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="326" InputScope="Default" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger>
                <i:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding textchangedcommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
```

Comment: You should go through the answers to your question and mark the best answer as accepted as soon as you have solved your problem. If the answers are lacking anything or are not solving your issue, you should comment below.

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtReview" MaxLength="1000" Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay,Path=Comments}"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="215" Margin="10,184,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="326" InputScope="Default" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding textchangedcommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```